# XML with Base64 Encoded string to PDF

Tags: java, xml, java-8, base64, decode

I have an XML wherein I am getting a PDF document as a Base64 Encoded string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
      <ns1:Record xmlns:ns1="urn:test.com:pdf">
         <Field>**Contains the base 64 encoded string of the actual PDF**</Field>
      </ns1:Record>
   </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

I have tried below to perform the conversion. I tried to take the XML content as input and perform the Base 64 conversion.

```
public void transform(TransformationInput transformationInput, TransformationOutput transformationOutput) throws StreamTransformationException {
        try {
            InputStream inputstream = transformationInput.getInputPayload().getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputstream = transformationOutput.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream();
            // Copy Input content to Output content
            byte[] b = new byte[inputstream.available()];
            inputstream.read(b);

                    Base64.Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
                byte[] decbytes = dec.decode(b);

           outputstream.write(decbytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

The tool that I use does not require main and the code is executed at runtime. But it does not work. I also tried removing the XML tags. And I have also imported java.util.Base64 separately in the import part of my tool. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation of InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29):

> It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

You must use a loop when reading from an InputStream.  And it is critical that you make use of the return value when you call InputStream.read, because there is no guarantee that your byte array will be filled.

You also need to remember to close your streams.  If you don’t, you will create a memory leak, and some data may not get written to the OutputStream.

Base64.Decoder has a useful method, [wrap(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap%28java.io.InputStream%29), which lets you treat decoding as an ordinary InputStream.

Finally:  Never write an empty `catch` block.  If you aren’t sure how to handle an exception, then don’t—remove the try/catch, add `throws IOException` to your method’s signature, and let a higher level of the application decide the best course of action (such as showing the end user an error message).

So, you’ll want something like this:

```
public void transform(TransformationInput transformationInput,
                      TransformationOutput transformationOutput)
throws StreamTransformationException,
       IOException {

    try (InputStream inputstream = Base64.getDecoder().wrap(
            transformationInput.getInputPayload().getInputStream());
        OutputStream outputstream =
            transformationOutput.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream()) {

        // Copy Input content to Output content
        byte[] b = new byte[inputstream.available()];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputstream.read(b)) >= 0) {
            outputstream.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

As of Java 9, you can use [InputStream.transferTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) to forego the byte array entirely:

```
public void transform(TransformationInput transformationInput,
                      TransformationOutput transformationOutput)
throws StreamTransformationException,
       IOException {

    try (InputStream inputstream = Base64.getDecoder().wrap(
            transformationInput.getInputPayload().getInputStream());
        OutputStream outputstream =
            transformationOutput.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream()) {

        inputstream.transferTo(outputstream);
    }
}
```

A word of caution:  I’m not sure what the TransformationInput and TransformationOutput classes are, but if TransformationOutput represents an XML file, binary data will not be compatible with it, as some byte values are not allowed to appear directly in XML documents.  This is why XML represents embedded binary data as hex or base 64.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. TransformationInput and TransformationOutput are part of SAP Mapping APIs. You can find the details in the [Mapping API]( https://help.sap.com/doc/javadocs_nw75_sps04/7.5.4/en-US/PI/com/sap/aii/mapping/api/TransformationInput.html) 
Additionally, I tried using an encoded text VGhpcyBpcyBhIHZlcnkgYmlnIHNlbnRlbmNl but it did not get decoded. And I am using Java 8 so cannot use the second option.

Comment: I did some more retries and found that I cannot use the XML tags for my input. If I just pass **VGhpcyBpcyBhIHZlcnkgYmlnIHNlbnRlbmNl** without any XML tags it gets converted to **This is a very big sentence** The input, however, will be XML.

Comment: Then you need to extract the content of the relevant XML element from your input.  [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) is quite useful for that.